# iptables IP address (source and destination IP address) mangling

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, router

I tried to understand the concept of iptables mangling part, but somehow failed to understand the IP header manipulative section.

For example: Below is the system scenario which I'm trying to correlate with the iptables.

We have an application which holds one IP (IP1 - pool 1) for all incoming and outgoing packets. Now, we need to define new interface IP against different POOL (IP2 - POOL2)for particular incoming/outgoing traffic need)

Need for an IPTABLE mangle :

We need IPtables to perform the below actions:

PREROUTING:
if the packet destination is IP2, then we need a "iptable mangle rule" to modify the destination address from IP2 to IP1 and leave the packet (so that packet will go the application and IP2 address behaves as forward IP on different interface & pool than IP1).

Query :

Is it possible to add one rule to achieve the above action? , if yes, could someone provide hint or pointer to frame one ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why can't the application listen on both IPs? That would be an easier solution than NATing the packet over to the other IP.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  What you are asking doesn't make a lot of sense.  You want to modify the destination, without actually changing the destination?

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek Yes, but application is too legacy and can't bound two IPs to listen. So only need NAT help to just fake the packet routing and also we need to measure the traffic on pool2

Comment: @Zoredache I'm not getting what you mean by "without actually changing the destination" if you mean without adding the IP to actual application, then yes. We don't want to bind two IP to listen instead we want NAT the destination IP to the existing one.

Comment: Maybe in simple term, if incoming packet destination IP (PRE) is X then I want to modify it to Y using iptables and also if the outgoing packet address is Y then like to change it to X (POST).Thanks in Advance.

Comment: listen on 0.0.0.0 and it should grab all interfaces, all IPs. Then you can use the firewall to filter by allowed destination IPs. You *could* use NAT for this, but that tends to cause more problems than it solves unless you get it exactly right.

Comment: I'd probably use haproxy here, rather then trying to do this via NAT.  Just set it up to act as a simple TCP proxy, which should perfectly accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek thanks for your information.

Comment: Is there any advantage on using NAT over netfilter hooks on custom .ko module ? Like if I have own customized module which binds book against PRE_ and POST_ handlers and do all mangling from that custom module instead of NAT ? which one is most optimized and recommended ? Thanks.